# Topological dynamical systems where all ergodic measures satisfy additional properties

Tags: probability, ergodic-theory, topological-dynamics

Consider a topological dynamical system (tds) $(X, T)$, i.e. a compact metric space $X$ and a continuous map $T : X \to X$ (perhaps a homeomorphism). The ergodic probability measures for $T$ are exactly the extreme points of the simplex $\mathcal{M}_T$ of $T$-invariant Borel probability measures on $X$.

My question: Is there a term for when a tds $(X, T)$ has the property that all ergodic measures for $(X, T)$ also satisfy some stronger ergodicity property (e.g. totally ergodic, weakly mixing, etc.)? Where can I learn more about them?

Here's what I know:

I know such systems exist. For example, take a measure-theoretic Bernoulli system and use Jewett-Krieger to find a uniquely ergodic model. Then the only ergodic measure for that uniquely ergodic model will be the Bernoulli measure. I can't think yet of any non-trivial examples of this phenomenon, though.

On the other hand, if we take an ergodic measure-theoretic dynamical system and use Jewett-Krieger to find a uniquely ergodic model for that system, then that uniquely ergodic model will have exactly one ergodic measure that's exactly as high on the ergodicity hierarchy as the one we started with. So, for example, an irrational rotation on the circle has exactly one ergodic measure (i.e. the Haar measure), but it's not weakly mixing.

Comment: My estimation is that there are no generally accepted terminology for the situation you are asking.

Comment: Roughly speaking, at least in the topological category (so conjugacies are required to be at least continuous), the space of invariant measures is large, and instead of asking for a property to be satisfied by all ergodic probabilities one common thing to do is to look for one (and only one if possible) ergodic probability with a predetermined property. E.g. in the context of thermodynamic formalism the notion of an equilibrium measure is an example of this.

Comment: Also, in a sense invoking the Jewett-Krieger theorem seems antithetical, as the associated isomorphism is not to be expected to be topological (as you said it possibly collapses the space of invariant measures to a singleton), whereas your question seems to be more interesting when there are multiple ergodic measures one needs to worry about.

Comment: Thus to me the question underlying your question seems to be of the form: "Given any property $P$ that an anonymous pair $(\mu,f)$ for $f$ a continuous self-map and $\mu$ an ergodic $f$-invariant probability may or may not satisfy, and is invariant under topological conjugacy, find the "intrinsically $P$" self-maps $f$; these are the maps $f$ such that for any $\mu$ the pair $(\mu,f)$ satisfies $P$."

Comment: In a sense unique ergodicity is a property like this: a priori "ergodicity" is valid for a pair $(\mu,f)$, but when for any $\mu$, $(\mu,f)$ is ergodic, then $f$ can be said to be ergodic without reference to a measure, and ergodicity is invariant under topological conjugacy.

Comment: @AlpUzman I mentioned the Jewett-Krieger bit just to make sure that some suitably nontrivial systems with the property I was thinking about existed. I'm struggling to think of any examples of such systems that aren't uniquely ergodic.